# Extracted SMS body and passing it in a condition (Python)

Tags: python, serial, pi-a

This is my class for checking unread messages

```
 def CheckUnreadMsgs(ser)
   print "Check for new messages...\n"
   ser.write("AT\r")
   time.sleep(3)
   line =  ser.read(size = 64)
   print line
   sen.write('AT+CMGL="REC UNREAD"\r')
   time.sleep(3)
   response = ser.read(size =200)
   print response
   return response
```

This is the main program.

```
print "Opening communications serial...\n"
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1',115200,timeout=1)
ser.open()
#check continous loop
print "Starting main loop\n"

while True:
  message = CheckUnreadMsgs(ser)
  a = message.find('\n') + 63
  b = len(message)
  msg = message[a:b]
  print msg
  if (msg == "on")
    print "Power ON Commanded!\n"
```

I have already extracted the body of the SMS but the variable doesn't seem to pass through the condition if (msg == "on"). Can you help me about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This my answer using **regex**.

```
print "Opening communications serial...\n"
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1',115200,timeout=1)
ser.open()
#check continous loop
print "Starting main loop\n"

while True:
  message = CheckUnreadMsgs(ser)
  a = message.find('\n') + 63
  b = len(message)
  msg = message[a:b]
  m = re.search("(pow.*)",msg)
  if m:
      mm = (m.group(1))
      if "on" in mm:
         print "Power On"
      elif "off" in mm:
         print "Power Off"
```